# How do I perform an action on publication within Wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail

I'd like to perform a function when a Wagtail `Page` object is published (specifically, I have a utility method that sends out emails notifying subscribers that a new blog page is available).

Is there a method I can override (either `save` or something else) that will let me run this function on publication, or even better, on first publication of the object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can connect to the `page_published` signal:

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/signals.html#page-published